# IoT-Core UWP MacAlgorithmProvider vs.NET 4.5 HMACSHA256 usage giving 403

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, windows-10-iot-core

Identical code except for the CreateAuthenticationHeader functions below. In .Net 4.5 MVC5 I can REST-access (REST, no storage library) an azure table without difficulty using this:

```
        private static string CreateAuthorizationHeader(string canonicalizedString)
    {
        var sharedKeyParts = SvcComsCommon.AzureStorageConnectStringDict();

        var signature = string.Empty;
        using (HMACSHA256 hmacSha256 = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(sharedKeyParts["AccountKey"])))
        {
            var dataToHmac = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(canonicalizedString);
            signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmacSha256.ComputeHash(dataToHmac));
        }

        var account = sharedKeyParts["AccountName"];
        var authorizationHeader = string.Format(
               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
               "{0} {1}:{2}",
               "SharedKey", 
               account,
               signature);
        return authorizationHeader;
    }
```

On Windows IoT-Core (UWP) newest from Oct. 2015 I use the following (since the above is not supported), which gives me a 403 error and complains that my signature is wrong. The rest of the code is identical. What is the nuance I am missing?

```
        private static string CreateAuthorizationHeader(string canonicalizedString)
    {
        var sharedKeyParts = SvcComsCommon.AzureStorageConnectStringDict(); // Just the Azure Storage Connection String as Dictionary. No tricks.

        var key = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(sharedKeyParts["AccountKey"], BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
        var msg = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(canonicalizedString, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);

        // Create HMAC.
        var objMacProv = MacAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(MacAlgorithmNames.HmacSha256);
        var hash = objMacProv.CreateHash(key);
        hash.Append(msg);
        var signature = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(hash.GetValueAndReset());

        // Header
        var account = sharedKeyParts["AccountName"];
        var authorizationHeader = string.Format(
               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
               "{0} {1}:{2}",
               "SharedKey", 
               account,
               signature);

        return authorizationHeader;
    }
```

I've read the other posts, still not seeing what is missing.

***Update*** Error message on IoT-Core RPi ARM

```
The operation identifier is not valid.
  at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x8d1eb9
   at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0xd0e30b
   at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0xd0e7af
   at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0xd0e715
   at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0xd0e69f
   at RpiHeadlessCS.Devices.HxaRs485Ftdi.<ReadAsync>d__26.MoveNext()
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in RpiHeadlessCS-uwp.Interop.dll
Read async error: The operation identifier is not valid.
```

Answer (score 0):

UWP has a bug in the framework pertaining to caching behavior that causes Auth errors for Azure Storage. They're working on a fix, but I'm not 100% sure when that fix will be deployed. Sorry about that!

Comment: Thanks. The workaround cited everywhere is "just use the REST API". So the bug also effects the REST API, apparently here in the mac libraries (at least). This essentially blocks any possible use of Azure Storage from IoT-Core/UWP no matter what? Frustrating to say the least, since this all works on other OSs. Fix it fast, please.

Comment: This has to do with the networking stack on UWP. I've escalated with that team and they're working on a fix. I'm very sorry for the inconvenience -- this will break all UWP REST calls to storage unfortunately, regardless of OS.

Comment: Thanks. Added the error output from RPi ARM console above.